# Configuring Project CRS to reflect degree coordinates

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

I have close to zero GIS background.

My goal is to extract only a certain UTM zone of this [land use tiff file](http://www.cec.org/tools-and-resources/map-files/land-cover-2005). I only know how to do that via specifying lat lon clipper box, however right now Qgis only shows things in pixel coordinate. Is there any way I can:

i. change project coordinates to lat/lon, or 
ii. extract UTM zone straight from the current one (meters from origin @ 45N100W)?

---

The docs show the projection as *Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area* Central Meridian *-100.0*, Lat of Origin *45.0* which to my knowledge corresponds to *US National Atlas Equal AREA EPSG:2163*

I've tried setting both layer and project CRS to the mentioned projection, but no avail.

Here's a screenshot + first bit of *gdalinfo*.

[image]

```
Size is 37000, 35000
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["Sphere_ARC_INFO_Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area",
    GEOGCS["Sphere_of_Radius_6370997m",
        DATUM["Sphere_of_Radius_6370997m",
            SPHEROID["Sphere of Radius 6370997m",6370997,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",45],
    PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",-100],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["meters",1]]
Origin = (-4418000.000000000000000,4876500.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (250.000000000000000,-250.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=IMAGINE TIFF Support
Copyright 1991 - 1999 by ERDAS, Inc. All Rights Reserved
@(#)$RCSfile: etif.c $ $Revision: 1.10.1.9.1.9.2.11 $ $Date: 2004/09/15 18:42:01EDT $
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-4418000.000, 4876500.000) 
Lower Left  (-4418000.000,-3873500.000) 
Upper Right ( 4832000.000, 4876500.000) 
Lower Right ( 4832000.000,-3873500.000) 
Center      (  207000.000,  501500.000)
```

Comment: Pixels are 250 metres... this is an odd SRS, not that I'm familiar will North American projections. I can see it's confusing but where is the problem? If you load other data does it align to where you'd expect or off the page?

Comment: sry, editted post to make things more clear. I need to extract an UTM zone, but I don't know how to do that without using lat/lon. Is there a way to display the coordinates to lat/lon as opposed to pixels?

Comment: These coordinates are not pixels, but meters from the origin of the projection. You might want the UTM zone boundaries shapefile from http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/coordsys/grids/universal_grid_system.html and clip your raster to the UTM zone you need. And you need to reproject your raster to WGS84, or the shapefile to the rasters CRS.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the CRS of the raster, use `Raster -> Projections -> Warp(Reproject)`, choosing a different filename and `WGS84 EPSG:4326` as target SRS.

**DO NOT** use `Set Layer CRS` for this task, it will corrupt your data.

To avoid future mistakes, remove the original layer from the canvas, and set the **project** CRS to WGS84 as well.

With the raster now in lat/lon, you can clip it to the degree bounds of the UTM zone you need.